# Youtube API - YoutubeVideoApp Zend example

Tags: youtube-api

I just downloaded the Youtube Zend library.
However, trying to run this sample app YoutubeVideoApp and running the "retrieve my videos" keeps on giving me this error.

ERROR Expected response code 200, got 403
Service Forbidden

What steps am I missing?
The following is what I did:
1. Set up a developer key and add that to the application
2. Add a new domain from https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains (my domain is in localhost and so Google can't verify it)

Would the fact that the domain can't be verified be the issue? (I have no access to an actual server from home)

Also the first time I run the web app, I saw the authentication popup. Now it no longer shows.
Where would I go to revoke permission so I can see that authentication popup again?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

Oh man... It actually works.
All I did was remove the session and then re-log in.

I think it was because initially I sign in to picassa using my gmail username/password and I have a different username/password for youtube.

Thanks,
Tee